# llvm: How to get the call graph for a module of external node

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am having a program lets consider myProgram.c which uses some library (user created library) lets say myLibrary.

```
#include "myLibrary.h"'

int main()
{
    //call some function in myLibrary lets say foo
    foo();
}
```

Now when I have created a module pass. And I am generating call graph.
Now in the call graph generated there is a node for the function foo() as follows:

Call graph node for function: 'foo'<<0x951d300>>  #uses=3
  CS<0x0> calls external node.

Now I want all the functions which will be called by this foo in the 
"myLibrary".

Is it possible? Can I get the call graph of myLibrary through the call graph node of the function foo in myProgram.c

Comment: Not sure you can do this without `mylibrary.c` or `mylibrary.ll`. If you look at `myProgram.ll` the function `foo` has an external global declaration only. In your scenario, is the library in binary form for linking to?

Comment: myLibrary is user created library i.e. I have the source code of library. I can compile and link it in whatever way I want. In this case, I compiled the library first and then compiled my code and tried to do the static linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this with the following steps, and was able to get all functions from call graph.

First my_program.c looks like

```
#include "my_library.h"
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

my_library.c is

```
#include "my_library.h"
void boo() {}

void foo()
{
    boo();
}

clang++ my_program.c -c -emit-llvm
clang++ my_library.c -c -emit-llvm
llvm-link my_program.bc my_library.bc -o linked.bc
```

Then I used a custom ModulePass to traverse call graph. To get the call graph the ModulePass uses llvm CallGraphWrapperPass pass.

If I use clang instead of clang++, CallGraph does not capture main calling foo, which is strange, but i don't have any explanation for this.

Comment: Actually I solved the problem and forgot to update. For clang I did it in the following ways.  1)clang my_program.c -S -emit-llvm -o my_program.ll         2)clang my_library.c -S -emit-llvm -o my_library.ll  3)llvm-link my_program.ll my_library.ll -o linked.ll -S